# How can I create this game-tree in Latex?

Tags: tables, arrows, trees

I have the following figure:

[image: Game tree]

As of now I create this in Word/Powerpoint and paste the screenshot in a LaTeX file. Is there a way to create this natively? Also, what would be the advantage of doing so?

The tables are just place holders and actual table design/content may change. But I prefer if it could be editable and not fixed. I'm not sure I even know where to start or how to go about it. I've never needed to draw anything in LaTeX before.

Comment: Please note that the tables would look much better without vertical lines.  I would also drop the top and bottom horizontal ones.  (Alternatively, you might try keeping only the second vertical and horizontal lines, those between the row and column headers and their contents - I didn't try this at home, it's almost 2:00 am here;), but I guess it might look ok.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using [`forest`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\newcommand\mytable[5]{%
#1\\
\begin{tabular}[t]{*{3}{|c}|}
\hline
& T1 & T2 \\
\hline
T1 & #2 & #3 \\
\hline
T2 & #4 & #5 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,l=2cm,edge={->}},
for descendants={text width=4.2cm,align=c}
[Developers
  [\mytable{Type I probability: 0.2}{A,B}{C,D}{E,F}{G,H}]
  [\mytable{Type II probability: 0.5}{P,Q}{R,S}{U,V}{W,X}]
  [\mytable{Type III probability: 0.3}{A,B}{C,D}{E,F}{G,H}]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As **mbork** notices in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163155/how-can-i-create-this-game-tree-in-latex#comment374136_163155), perhaps you can avoid most of the lines in the tables:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\newcommand\mytable[5]{%
#1\\[1ex]
{%
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}%
\begin{tabular}[t]{c|cc}
& T1 & T2 \\
\hline
T1 & #2 & #3 \\
T2 & #4 & #5 \\
\end{tabular}%
}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,l=2cm,edge={->}},
for descendants={text width=4.2cm,align=c}
[Developers
  [\mytable{Type I probability: 0.2}{A,B}{C,D}{E,F}{G,H}]
  [\mytable{Type II probability: 0.5}{P,Q}{R,S}{U,V}{W,X}]
  [\mytable{Type III probability: 0.3}{A,B}{C,D}{E,F}{G,H}]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Any way to get the middle line straight and along with arrowheads?

Comment: @JPi `forest` uses `TikZ`.

Comment: @PhD arrow tips added.

Comment: @PhD Initially I overlooked the other requirement, now I've added the options to my answer.

Comment: Great!!! Thanks a ton! Learnt something new today!

Answer (score 8):

You have quite a few options for this- the [`tikz`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tikz) package is very powerful and can be used in a variety of different ways.

In the code below I have used the `positioning` library.

[image: screenshot]

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (developers){Developers};
    \node (probI)[below left=of developers,align=center]{Type I: Probability\\
        \begin{tabular}{ccc}
            1 & 2 & 3 \\
            1 & 2 & 3 \\
        \end{tabular}
    };
    \node (probII)[below =of developers,align=center]{Type II: Probability\\
        \begin{tabular}{ccc}
            1 & 2 & 3 \\
            1 & 2 & 3 \\
        \end{tabular}
    };
    \node (probIII)[below right=of developers,align=center]{Type III: Probability\\
        \begin{tabular}{ccc}
            1 & 2 & 3 \\
            1 & 2 & 3 \\
        \end{tabular}
    };
    % draw the connections
    \draw[->] (developers)--(probI);
    \draw[->] (developers)--(probII);
    \draw[->] (developers)--(probIII);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You can adjust the placement of the arrows by using, for example,

```
\draw[->] (developers)--(probI.north);
\draw[->] (developers)--(probII);
\draw[->] (developers)--(probIII.north);
```

which gives

[image: screenshot]

Or else

```
\draw[->] (developers.south)--(probI.north);
\draw[->] (developers.south)--(probII);
\draw[->] (developers.south)--(probIII.north);
```

which gives

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 8):

Same as cmhughes answer but with fine adjustments.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (a) at (0,0) {Developers};
  \node[below left=3cm and 4cm of a,align=center,anchor=east] (b) {%
             Type I: Probability = 0.2\\
             \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}\hline
                & 2 & 3 \\\hline
             4 & 5 & 6 \\\hline
             7 & 8 & 9 \\\hline
             \end{tabular}
             };
  \node[below=3cm of a,align=center,anchor=center] (c) {%
             Type I: Probability = 0.5\\
             \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}\hline
                & 2 & 3 \\\hline
             4 & 5 & 6 \\\hline
             7 & 8 & 9 \\\hline
             \end{tabular}
             };
  \node[below right=3cm and 4cm of a,align=center,anchor=west] (d) {%
             Type I: Probability = 0.3\\
             \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}\hline
                & 2 & 3 \\\hline
             4 & 5 & 6 \\\hline
             7 & 8 & 9 \\\hline
             \end{tabular}
             };
    \draw[->] (a.south)--(b.north);
    \draw[->] (a.south)--(c.north);
    \draw[->] (a.south)--(d.north);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Adjust the positioning (by changing `3cm and 4cm`)  depending upon the content and size of the table.